# iOS Dynamic Content View inside ScrollView not scrolling properly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have created a `ViewController` that has `ScrollView` direct child of its `View` now I have added a `View` inside `ScrollView` that has constrains :

[image]
[image]

I have added a `VerticalLayout` class with following code:

```
class VerticalLayout: UIView {

    var yOffsets: [CGFloat] = []
    var heightValue : CGFloat = 0.0

    init(width: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:0))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        var height: CGFloat = 0

        for i in 0..<subviews.count {
            let view = subviews[i] as UIView
            view.layoutSubviews()
            height += yOffsets[i]
            view.frame.origin.y = height
            height += view.frame.height
        }

        self.frame.size.height = height
        self.heightValue = height

    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        yOffsets.append(view.frame.origin.y)
        super.addSubview(view)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        for view in subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        yOffsets.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    }

}
```

And `ViewController` code as :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var contentview: UIView!


    @IBOutlet var scrollview: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let vLayout = VerticalLayout(width: view.frame.width)
        vLayout.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        contentview.addSubview(vLayout)

        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.red))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.magenta))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.green))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.blue))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.yellow))
        contentview.frame.size.height = vLayout.heightValue
        contentview.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func getView(color:UIColor) -> UIView
    {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:50, width:100, height:100))
        view.backgroundColor = color
        return view
    }
}
```

But when I run this code I get this screen:

[image]

And the content of this screen is not scrollable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works well with me , Also I think that vertical `UIStackView` is perfect for issues like that instead of manually handling views

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet var contentview: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        contentview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        let vLayout = VerticalLayout(width: view.frame.width)

        vLayout.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        contentview.addSubview(vLayout)

        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.red))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.magenta))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.green))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.blue))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.yellow))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.red))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.magenta))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.green))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.blue))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.yellow))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.red))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.magenta))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.green))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.blue))
        vLayout.addSubview(getView(color: UIColor.yellow))

    }

    func getView(color:UIColor) -> UIView
    {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:50, width:100, height:100))
        view.backgroundColor = color
        return view
    }


}

class VerticalLayout: UIView {

    var yOffsets: [CGFloat] = []
    var heightValue : CGFloat = 0.0

    init(width: CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width, height:0))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        var height: CGFloat = 0

        for i in 0..<subviews.count {
            let view = subviews[i] as UIView
            view.layoutSubviews()
            height += yOffsets[i]
            view.frame.origin.y = height
            height += view.frame.height
        }

        // main edit is here

        self.frame.size.height = height

        self.heightValue = height

        let ff = self.superview

        let dd = ff?.superview as! UIScrollView

        dd.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: self.frame.size.width, height: height)

    }

    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        yOffsets.append(view.frame.origin.y)
        super.addSubview(view)
    }

    func removeAll() {
        for view in subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        yOffsets.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here You are missing scroll view content size. Please set scrollview content size after adding views.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: height of total no of views, height: width of the screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just set constraint of content view as like

1. Top to super view
2. leading to a super view
3. trailing to a super view
4. bottom to super view
5. Equal width to a super view
6. Equal height to super view

And the last in tap on equal height constraint and set low priority(250).

Your scroll will work perfectly.

[image]